# MYSQL query assistance with wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, where-clause

first, here is how the mysql data looks like:

```
"group" column in "table_a"
---------------
user1 = 123,456,789
user2 = 789,897,12
user3 = 789
user4 = 4789,123,456
---------------
```

I am trying to return all users who have "789" in their group column field.

I have:

```
SELECT * from table_a WHERE group LIKE %789%
```

this query returns user1,user2,user3,user4 (user4 should not be part of the results)

and:

```
SELECT * from table_a WHERE group LIKE %789%
```

only returns user3

How can I return only user1, user2 and user3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your query is missing single quotes around the right operand of `like`:

```
where grp like '%789%'
```

However please note that this is not a reliable to check if a value belongs to a comma-separated list, since it would partially match on any value. If your list is like `'123,45,67890'`, then the like expression would match, while you probably don't want that.

I would recommend `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set('789', grp)
```

Finally: you should not have a data model where multiple numbers are stored in a single string columns. Instead, you should have another table, where each value is stored on a separate row. More about this can be read in [this famous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716).

Note: `group` is a language keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name; I renamed it to `grp` in the above code snippets;

Comment: thank you so much, find_in_set() did the trick